# Make all files in a folder as long as the longest file

Tags: bash, for-loop, awk, sh

I've got many `.txt` files that contain many lines with a single column of data. However, the length of the files are not the same. Some files have 2000 lines, others 2001 lines etc.

Sometimes there's a single blank line at the end which I want to remove.

I want to append lines of 0 to the end of all but the longest file, so that the line numbers of all files are equal.

I would like this to be solved with a simple shell script.

Comment: You want to add a blank line to all files that contain only 2000 lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to find the file with the most lines. After that, you can append lines to the other files until they have as many lines as the file with the most lines.

Here we append lines containing the text `0` until the file has as many lines as the file with the most lines.

To remove a blank line at the ending first, you can use `sed`:

```
sed -i '${/^$/d}' /home/kisa/data/*.txt
max=$(wc -l /home/kisa/data/*.txt | head -n-1 | sort -n | awk 'END {print $1}')
for f in /home/kisa/data/*.txt; do
  n=$(wc -l < "$f")
  yes 0 | head -n $((max-n)) >> "$f"
done
```